# Adaptive / Responsive Design for different table layout on mobile?

Tags: mobile, responsive-design, adaptive-design

... I'm trying to figure out whether the following is possible switching from desktop to mobile:

[Mobile to desktop- different table design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CnZ6.jpg)

Basically on the desktop I'm planning on the item description appearing in the info box on mouseover, but on mobile I'd like the info to simply display in a table. My question is: is this possible using only CSS or is there some server-side shenanigans I'd need to employ when rendering the page in terms of different HTML includes?

The only thing I can think off the top of my head is some sort of complicated showing / hiding of elements using @media queries plus some fiddly placement, but I feel like there must be a straightforward way to achieve this?

If anyone can point me in the right direction I'd be greatly...er..grateful!

Thanks!
Stu

Comment: Have you looked at bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com?

Comment: I have, and will look into it further! Planning on using it for the main design, but I was under the impression that it wouldn't work 'out of the box' for this due to the particular placement / movement of the boxes.... maybe if I do it in two columns (images and description)?

(Still getting my head around it ;))